# Cannot get the checkbox.checked property

Tags: jquery, asp.net, checkbox

I have some ASP.Net code that defines a server-side checkbox like this:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="_chkWindAndHail" runat="server" Text="Wind / Hail Deductible" TextAlign="Right" Checked="true" onClick="onControlChanged()" />
```

Then in the client-side event handler I have some Javascript that looks like this:

```
var chkWind = $("#<%= _chkWindAndHail.ClientID %>");
var hdnWind = $("#<%= _hdnWindAndHailPremium.ClientID %>");
var txtWind = $("#<%= _txtWindAndHailPremium.ClientID %>");
if (chkWind.checked)
    txtWind.val(hdnWind.val);
else
    txtWind.val(0);
```

When I try to look at the value of the "checked" property of the textbox, Firebug says the checkbox object is good but the "checked" property comes up "undefined" and thus in code it never sets a proper value.

Can someone explain to me what the heck I'm doing wrong?  I'm new to JQuery, so this is probably something very basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fastest way is to get the `checked` property, but you need to do it from the DOM element itself stored in the jQuery object.

```
chkWind[0].checked;
```

This retrieves the DOM element at index `0`, and gives you the `checked` property. You were trying to get it from the jQuery object instead of the element.

Comment: That works; interesting.  Why do I need to reference it like an array? I'm only retrieving a single instance of a control.

Comment: @Mike: Because a jQuery object is an Array-like object. When you do a DOM selection, you're getting back an object that references the matched elements at numeric indices. In your case, you seem to be selecting one element, so you can just access it at the first index `[0]`. An alternative is to use `.get(0)` to get a DOM element at an index, but the square bracket (Array) notation should be a little faster.

Comment: How would you contrast this technique with Loktar's suggestions, above?  All 3 seem to work.  Is there a best practice?

Comment: @Mike: Definitely don't use `.is()`. It is slow. The `.attr()` would be better if you really want to use a jQuery method. Overall, accessing the property directly is the fastest, and requires the least code. The `checked` property is fully cross-browser compatible too.

Comment: Made this so you can check out the differences yourself. http://jsperf.com/jquery-checked the checked property is by far the fastest way like patrick dw has pointed out.

Comment: Thanks guys for your help! Loktar, thanks so much for the very cool JsPerf tests.  I have never seen that site before.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
.is(':checked');
```

or

```
.attr('checked');
```

Both should bring back the result you are looking for.

Comment: These both work.  I need to do some more reading on these functions.  Curious that using this syntax, I don't have to reference "node 0" the way I do with chkWind[0].checked

Answer (score 0):

Try chkWind.attr('checked') to access the attribute. Values returned as true/false.